# Java - Uncommon sort a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I need help with this exercise

Consider you have 2d array

```
String[][]myArray={
        {"0.0","0.1","0.2","0.3","0.4"},
        {"1.0","1.1","1.2","1.3"},
        {"2.0","2.1","2.2","2.3","2.4","2.5"}
        };
```

and you wish to print:

```
0.0|1.0|2.0|
0.1|1.1|2.1|
0.2|1.2|2.1|
0.3|1.3|2.3|
0.4|2.4|
2.5|
```

I have tried to use Comparator

Here is code :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[][]Array={
            {"0.0","0.1","0.2","0.3","0.4"},
            {"1.0","1.1","1.2","1.3"},
            {"2.0","2.1","2.2","2.3","2.4","2.5"}
            };

    Arrays.sort(Array, new PorKolumn(2));

    for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {

        String [] kol = Array[i];
        for(int j=0; j<kol.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(kol[j] + " | ");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    }


}

class PorKolumn implements Comparator{
    int Kolumny;

    public PorKolumn(int Kolumny) {
        this.Kolumny = Kolumny;

    }
    public int compare (Object o1, Object o2 ){
        String [] kol1 = (String []) o1;
        String [] kol2 = (String []) o2;

        return kol1[Kolumny].compareTo(kol2[Kolumny]);

    }'
```

Thx for any help.

Comment: so you want to sort each array, then sort the array based on their first value after been sorted right?

Comment: Do you just want to print inner Arrays Vertically??

Comment: I'm not seeing any sorting.  I'm seeing you print the inner arrays vertically, and then pushing everything as far to the left as possible.

Comment: Please describe the exact sort order you need. An example is not enough...

Comment: **Yeah, true there is no sorting method, i forgot pasted . Your answers  showed me the path. Thanks all of you. Really Great place and people :). Next time I will be more careful. Thanks once more.**

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void print( String[][] a ){
    int iRow = 0;
    while(true){
        boolean done = false;
        for( int iCol = 0; iCol < a.length; iCol++ ){
             if( iRow < a[iCol].length ){
                System.out.print( a[iCol][iRow] + "|" );
                done = true;
             }
        }
        if( ! done ) break;
        System.out.println();
        iRow++;
    }
}
```

Prints as requested:

```
0.0|1.0|2.0|
0.1|1.1|2.1|
0.2|1.2|2.2|
0.3|1.3|2.3|
0.4|2.4|
2.5|
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Teepeemm stated  there is no sorting:

```
String[][]myArray={
        {"0.0","0.1","0.2","0.3","0.4"},
        {"1.0","1.1","1.2","1.3"},
        {"2.0","2.1","2.2","2.3","2.4","2.5"}
        };

    int maxLength = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
        if(maxLength < myArray[i].length)
            maxLength = myArray[i].length;

    for(int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
            if(j < myArray[i].length) 
                System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + "|");
        System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
0.0|1.0|2.0|
0.1|1.1|2.1|
0.2|1.2|2.2|
0.3|1.3|2.3|
0.4|2.4|
2.5|
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:
(This is untested code, because i have written it directly here)

```
int i = 0;
boolean ongoing = true;

while(ongoing){

  for(int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++){
    if(myArray[j][i] == null){
      System.out.print("\t|");
      ongoing = false;
      continiue;
    }
    ongoing = true;
    System.out.print(myArray[j][i]+"\t|");
  }  
  System.out.print("\n");
  i++;
}
```

it should give out the right format.